# Problem with rosdep when trying to check for dependencies

Tags: ros, ros2

I am trying to run the following rosdep command to check for missing dependencies in my ROS2 package:

`rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro galactic -y`

However, when I try to run this line of code in my terminal, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('rosdep==0.21.0', 'console_scripts', 'rosdep')())
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .lookup import RosdepDefinition, RosdepView, RosdepLookup, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .sources_list import SourcesListLoader
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .gbpdistro_support import get_gbprepo_as_rosdep_data, download_gbpdistro_as_rosdep_data
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/gbpdistro_support.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .platforms.redhat import YUM_INSTALLER
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosdep2/platforms/redhat.py", line 34, in <module>
    from rospkg.os_detect import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'OS_ALMALINUX' from 'rospkg.os_detect' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rospkg-1.2.8-py3.8.egg/rospkg/os_detect.py)
```

I tried to search on the forums to see if anyone had an error with importing 'OS_ALMALINUX' but I couldn't find any similar case.
Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Probably you don't have a supported Linux version. What Linux do you have ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04. But ubuntu is supported by ros2.

Comment: oh ok and just to make sure, you actually did source your environment before running the coammand as described here https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Configuring-ROS2-Environment.html#source-the-setup-files

Comment: Yes, it is already in my bashrc file. So, when I open a new terminal, the environment is automatically sourced.

Comment: odd, sorry can't help just  just that following all the tutorial steps until rosdep doesn't fail. Probably something is missing there.

Comment: Alright,, Thank you

Comment: Have you resolved this problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to remove `rospkg` from `pip` (`pip uninstall rospkg`) and use `rospkg` installed from `apt` instead (`sudo apt install python3-rospkg`). It seems that the incorrect version was installed through `pip` or that there was some conflict between the `pip` and `apt` versions.